# how to use custom login page in salesforce community instead of default?

Tags: salesforce

I have created custom login page in my community. But when I just enter domain in browser, it redirects me to default login page 'mycommunity.force.com/login'.
How can I use my custom login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Url redirect from '/login' to '/CustomLogin'